# How to create a global integer variable without assigning any value?

Tags: javascript

```
var add = function() {
        var total_income = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < income_amount.length; i++) {
            total_income = total_income + income_amount[i];

        }
        return total_income;
    }
    var balance = add();
```

My function is not returning the updated value and its is assigning the current value i.e 0 so how can i get an updated value

Comment: what is `income_amount`?

Comment: Where is the value updated? What is it returning?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the income_amount and I got `300` as result

```
 var income_amount=[100,200];
    var add = function() {
            var total_income = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < income_amount.length; i++) {
                total_income = total_income + income_amount[i];

            }
            console.log(total_income);
            return total_income;
    }
    var balance = add();
```

Your code is working fine.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if I try your code the results is correct, give a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6T9zh/)

I initialized the `income_amount` variable for test:

```
var income_amount = [1,2,3,4];
```